# Centos wont create init.d startup files

Tags: init.d

recently i installed vnstat on my fresh linux machine.

so after installing it with `yum install vnstat` , before it i installed epel!

so now i cant start it: `service vnstat start`
error: `unrecognized service`

i have tired searching a little then i found out that it does not create init.d file to run it.

i dont prefer to create them manually i want it fixed please help.

how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 yum update 
 reboot system
 yum install vnstat    ( gd and libXpm is dependencies for vnstat )
 service vnstat start
 chkconfig vnstat on
 service vnstat restart ( for check its running properly or not :) )
```

Comment: More explanation needed

Answer (score 0):

after adding `vnstat` file to `/etc/init.d` folder

and `service vnstat start`  [ also it has no returns ]

and `vnstat -u` problem fixed.

`vnstat` startup file can be found here
http://humdi.net/vnstat/init.d/redhat/vnstat

thanks to all. [ Problem Fixed ]